# CPView tiled background?

Tags: cappuccino, objective-j

Is there a way to tile an image in objective-j on a CPView?
something along the lines of:

- [CPImage alloc] initWithPatternImage:@"Resources/grid.png" size:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)]

Thanks guys ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var image = [[CPImage alloc]
                initWithContentsOfFile:"Resources/myimage.gif"
                                  size:CGSizeMake(20, 20)]; 
var imageView = [[CPImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,500,500)];    
[imageView setBackgroundColor:[CPColor colorWithPatternImage:image]];
```

Comment: You can set the background on any view, and you _shouldn't_ set it on an image view usually. Just remove the imageView line, and call the same thing on the regular view.

patternImage's are automatically tiled when they are view backgrounds.